How to search in multiple fields with Searchkick/ES in Rails
I've indexed the name, location, and designation fields on the Employee model. When I search for a term, it should match any of those fields. For example, if the name is John and the location is London, searching for "John," "John London," or "London" should return results. However, searching for "John London" should not return results for "John Germany."
What configurations do I need to implement to achieve this?

“I search for a term, it should match any of those fields.” - seems to be doing what you asked. Please share your search code in the question.
